# Is there a simple image processor that can reduce image color depth (convert 24-bit RGB to 2, 4 or 8-bit indexed color)?

Tags: software-recommendation, files, image-processing, png, color-depth

I have a need for a quick/easy image processing application under Ubuntu 18.04 that will allow me to view, crop, scale down and reduce color depth/color mode (number of color bits per pixel) - with and without dithering - of 24-bit JPG input images and export them as PNG. I'd like the option of reducing to 4, 16 or 256 colors (2, 4 or 8 bits per pixel).

GIMP has these capabilities, but I'm looking for something less bulky.

In Windows (and OS/2 before that!), I was a longtime user of PMView, a speedy viewer and processor. I can continue to use PMView through WINE (there is also an IrfanView app that works similarly through WINE), but I would prefer a Linux app.

I have tried a number of applications. I like the simplicity, cropping, resizing and even the color manipulations of gThumb. But gThumb does not allow me to save a PNG at less than 24-bit. Same problem with Shotwell and Mirage. I've had no luck getting usable results with Pinta.

Comment: Have you looked at the command line [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) suite? It isn't the most user-friendly, but it will be the lightest and fastest to use. Especially for bulk actions.

Comment: @Thomas Hunt if I am not mistaken, indexed color PNGs always use 24 bits per palette entry.

Comment: I thought "indexed" was a synonym for "palette-based." In any event, I am looking to create lower bits-per-pixel forms of PNG as per http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html#png.ch08.div.5.1

Comment: Please respond to people who have contributed to your question in any manner by using `@` before their username, typing the first couple or so letters and then using tab to complete the entry. If you don't, it's possible people may not know you've responded. In your last comment, you should use **@terdon**.

Comment: Thanks, @terdon . I did look into ImageMagick, but was discouraged by the idea of using a command line utility to achieve a graphics purpose. I will give it a try. (It is capable of getting the job done, but I'm not entirely comfortable with the approach. I'll try running from a script. The ease of execution may offset my concerns over doing the task blind.)